# Proper Ruby on Rails YARD Tags Interpolation in Ruby Mine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine, yard

Want to setup Yard properly in Ruby Mine and any advice would be appreciated.

```rb
class Entity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

# @param user [User]
def authorized_for_user?(user)
  return true
end

# @param entity [Entity]
def check_authorization(entity)
  authorized_for_user?(entity.user) # The line that gets the following error
end
```

Since `.user` is through an active record belongs-to association, the warning I get is:

```rb
Incompatible types
Required: User
Passed: ActiveRecord::Associations::BelongsToAssociation<User>
```

Any idea how to make this automatically interpolate either. Will there be unintended side effects?

I want to get as close to documented typings as possible on important methods and services. I would appreciate any good tutorials / guides on how to achieve this?

Comment: There might be an issue on RubyMine's side so it's worth submitting an issue directly on the tracker with a project sample: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RUBY

Comment: It's true that the file types are different, I just want to be able to cast the belongsToAssosciation to just be User and not have to accept both in my yard doc annotations